# nodejs e express com conection timeout(h13) no heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

Olá, tenho uma api no heroku e elá se comunica com a api do pagseguro(notificações), a roda que lida com a notificação precisa pegar o codigo da transação que é recebido por post, fazer uma consulta na api do pagseguro pra pegar os status e mais alguns dados, depois disso precisa acessar meu banco pra consultar algumas tabelas e atualizar outras(adicionar moedas ao usuario e registrar no fluxo) o problema que estou encontrando é o h13(conection timeout). quando coloco o codigo em outro servidor o erro permanece
minha rota:

```js
router.post("/notificacao", function (req, res) {
    const parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
    const request = require("request");
    if (req.body.notificationType == "transaction") {
        console.log("reconheceu o type")
        if (req.body.notificationCode) {
            const link = "https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v3/transactions/notifications/"
                + req.body.notificationCode
                + "?email=****&token=****";
            console.log(link);
            request.get(link, (error, response, body) => {
                if (error) {
                    res.status(503).send({ status: "erro" })
                    return console.dir(error);
                }
                // return
                parseString(body, function (err, result) {
                    const status = result.transaction.status
                    Transacao.select(null, [{ name: "cod_transacao", value: result.transaction.code }])
                        .then((rowsT, fieldsR) => {
                            rowsT = rowsT[0]
                            console.log("rowsT", rowsT)
                            const notData = {
                                cod_transacao: result.transaction.code,
                                cod_mod: req.body.notificationCode,
                                status: result.transaction.status,
                                data_modificacao: fecha.format(new Date(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
                            }
                            // console.log("o q eu consultei", rowsT[0].instalador_id)
                            if ((parseInt(status) == 3 || parseInt(status) == 4) && rowsT.moedas != "adicionadas") {
                                console.log("add moedas")
                                const Instalador = require("../../instalador/instalador.js")
                                Instalador.addMoedas(rowsT.instalador_id, rowsT.id_plano).then(() => {
                                    notData['moedas'] = 'adicionadas'
                                    Transacao.update(notData).then((rows, fields) => {
                                        res.status(200).send(rows)
                                    })
                                })
                            } else {
                                if (parseInt(status) > 5) {
                                    if (rowsT.moedas = 'adicionadas') {
                                        const Instalador = require("../../instalador/instalador.js")
                                        Instalador.removeMoedas(rowsT.instalador_id, rowsT.id_plano).then(() => {
                                            notData['moedas'] = 'removidas'
                                            Transacao.update(notData).then((rows, fields) => {
                                                res.status(200).send(rows)
                                            })
                                        })
                                    } else {
                                        Transacao.update(notData).then((rows, fields) => {
                                            res.status(200).send(rows)
                                        })
                                    }
                                }

                            }


                        }).catch((error => {
                            res.status(500).send({
                                erro: String(err)
                            })
                        }))
                });
            });
        }
    }
    console.log(req.body)
})
```

a mensagem de erro é:

```
Dec 26 02:56:07 api-webar-teste heroku/router:  at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/financeiro/transacao/notificacao" host=****.herokuapp.com request_id=940e82ff-ae69-41c6-8c4e-da22cea9f5eb fwd="186.234.144.18" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=26003ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mudei minha conexão do banco para uma pool
como nos docs

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host            : 'example.org',
  user            : 'bob',
  password        : 'secret',
  database        : 'my_db'
});
 
pool.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});
```

isso resolveu os timeouts